# in which path should i need to put the text file to write in android

Tags: android

I have an android app and i need to write some string values in text file. i have coding to write in a text file. but i don't know where should i create my text file.Please  refer my code below,

```
FileOutputStream fOut = null; 

OutputStreamWriter osw = null; 

try{ 

fOut = openFileOutput(“public.dat”, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

osw.write(“TEXT”);

osw.close(); 

fOut.close(); 

}catch(Exception e){ 

e.printStackTrace(System.err); 

}
```

please inform me in which path should i create the text file.

Comment: http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html

Comment: You need to tell us what your text file is supposed to be good for before we can tell you where to store it.

Comment: @Class: i plan to write some datas in text file. if i put my text file in asset folder i think its impossible to write in it,thats y i need in which folder should i place my text file.

Comment: @sivanesan My question was: _What is your text file supposed to be good for_?

Comment: @class: i want to save my all datas as private. because i want to put encrypted login credentials. its for backup only.also i dont have sd card in my mobile . so i need another possible path

Comment: @sivanesan I have answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store data locally to your app, on the device's internal file system (not on external SD card), you should always consider [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), which are, by default, private files in the private storage space of your app, with convenient access.

SharedPreferences are perfect for key/value pairs, but not very suitable for certain data formats. So if you have different needs, the `Context` class has a broad variety of methods on offer. Please note that both `Activity` and `Application` objects are `Context`s so you'll always be able to access these. Please refer to the documentation:

- [getDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
- [getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29)
- [openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

There are also methods to get the path where external SD cards are mounted on the particular device, for temporary files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create the file in the directory of your application in sdcard.

```
fOut = openFileOutput(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+“/yourAppFolder/public.dat”, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: This is very bad advice. First, hardcoding paths is a no-go. Second, the original poster has not even said whether or not he wants his data private or public, as backup or app state, etc.

Comment: @Adnan: is it any other path avail except sd card

Comment: @sivanesan i don't think you can create/edit file in asset/Raw folder, since it is packed(.apk) and not expandable in size. so you have to create file in the sd Card.

Comment: if i use text file in internal memory storage of mobile device then where should i place the text file.

Comment: @AdnanAmjad Your following statement: "One can't create a file in the asset folder, so you have to create file in the sd Card" is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a best optimal solution but it is worth full if it is working..